# Adding states in a button in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to know if there is a way to add states to a button in flex 4 in addition to the default states that are present. I am unable to find any material on this. Kindly guide me to an appropriate resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can add something like: `[SkinState("myNewState")];` to a component which extends from Spark Button.

You can also make your own ButtonSkin add states there as well: 
`<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="disabled"/>
</s:states>`

I've used it to extend a TextInput but I assume it's the same for a Button :)